# Minimizing Column values in Microsoft Excel toward an optimum

Tags: microsoft-excel

In the below picture is a plot of `144 measurements` in `Column A` shown on the graph.

[image: Original data]

I decided that i want to make all the values nearer to `4300` which is in the middle, so i can show the before and after effect of the optimization. Now the sole purpose is for the sake of showing a visual example rather than a mathematical one. But then i decided i should do it numerically using `Solver optimization` in Microsoft Excel and here how i did it: In `column B` i assumed that it is `=ABS(SUM(B1;-4300))` applied to entire `Column B` and in `D2` is the total Sum of all values in `Column B`. Now my optimization problem as a first trial was to Minimize `D2` to a certain value e.g. `15000` where Solver will modify values in `Column A` to reach this objective and where also i would receive new values in `Column A` that are nearer to `4300`.

In the Second picture you can see the result.

[image]

My problem is here: although i succeeded to minimize my data toward a certain value, what i really need to fix is the fact that there are some values "farther" than the others, hence they don't "deserve" to be as equally closer as the nearer values to `4300`. We can think about it as a higher penalty factor for far values and a lower penalty for nearer values. How and where should i introduce this penalty factor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A linear mapping relationship moves the mean of the data, but does not affect its dispersion (or standard deviation).

If you want to make data move differently depending on how far away it is from the mean, you need to define a mapping relationship.

For example, you might use a linear transformation:
New value = New Mean + (Old value - Old Mean)*Factor
When Factor is 1.0, the data move without changing dispersion. When Factor is less than 1 (but more than 0), the data move closer to the mean, but data that were originally farther away from the mean move more.

If the data are characterized by a normal distribution (I can't tell because you didn't post a workbook), then you might first determine the Z statistic, which measures how many standard deviations the datum is from the mean:
Z =(Old value - Old Mean)/Old Standard Deviation

You can then use that Z statistic to determine a new value (still following a normal distribution) that has a new mean and new standard deviation. To perform this remapping, you would use the inverse of the previous formula:
=New Mean + Z*New Standard Deviation

By using the Z statistic and inverse mapping relationship described above, the new data retains its normal distribution, only with a new mean and standard deviation. It also retains a link to the original data.

I used the Z statistic and inverse mapping relationship to transform a set of unacceptable data shown in screenshot below.
[image: Original process parameter does not meet specifications]

The transformed data shown in screenshot below simulates how it might look with the mean raised and the standard deviation reduced so most of the points fall between the specification limits.
[image: After process change, the parameter meets specifications]